# Joomla Generating Unique URL for an Article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a page which was created by k2 extension and I have a xml file whose data is updated every minute(I download and overwrite it by crontab every minute). In that xml file there are match results current standings and topscorers and I display those results on the page. Every match result and current standing and topscorers are between  tags because whenever a link is clicked another window should be poped up which contains corresponding information which will be supplied again with that xml file.

Briefly whenever you click on a link there should be created a new page with full joomla support(a new joomla article or component or whatever I don't have any idea).

I have managed to popup a new php page with a unique url and I have also displayed corresponding information from xml but this php page is not related to joomla.

So I am trying to create unique URLs for each match result. So whenever someone clikcs on a match result a new window with unique URL (but same article) should be opened and the corresponding information is fetched with the following code

```
<xsl:value-of select="@sport"></xsl:value-of>:   <xsl:value-of select="@template"></xsl:value-of> - <xsl:value-of select="@tournament"></xsl:value-of>
        <span style="float: right;">
            <a href='xmlstore.php?type=standing&amp;tsid={$stage}' class="popup">Standing</a> ::: 
            <a href='xmlstore.php?type=topscorer&amp;tsid={$stage}' class="popup">Topscorer</a>
        </span>
```

This code works actually perfectly, whenever a match score is clicked a new page with a unique url is created but I couldn't find anyway to bind this xmlstore.php to my joomla article. Even I am not sure if there is anyway to do that.

Comment: I read you question 3 times and 1) I'm still not sure what you already have and 2) what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cppl thats because I am completely new and lost in joomla sorry. Is it now clearer? you can actually redirect me with your questions and I can give you the details that you need. I have updated my question with more details

Comment: I think you need to read up on how to make extensions for Joomla. Try this answer for some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501437/joomla-3-plugin-design/18501687#18501687